# How to get rid of whitespace in a string, php

Tags: php

So, I've tried using trim and str_replace, and I just can't figure it out.  I've googled it, and nothing seems to be working.

here is my code:

```
function convertcurrency($euro){
if (is_numeric($euro)) {
    $currency = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=".$euro."EUR%3D%3FUSD");
    $contents = array_map('trim', explode(" ", $currency));
    $getint = array_map('trim', explode("\"", $contents[3]));
    unset($getint[0]);
    $usdollar = implode(" ", $getint);
    echo "$euro Euro's is equal to $usdollar U.S. Dollars";
}
else{
    echo "$euro is not a number, please enter a number.";
}
}

convertcurrency(123123);

?>
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I apologize, I should have posted my output, and expected output.

Output: 123123 Euro's is equal to 162 362.3 U.S. Dollars 
Expected output: 123123 Euro's is equal to 162362.3 U.S. Dollars

Once I get rid of the whitespace, I can use the money_format function to display it properly.

Comment: Where are you observing this whitespace? In the resultant HTML page?

Comment: Could you post current output and expected output? "nothing seems to be working" isn't a real specific list of problems :). What do you want, preferably, why do you want it? what happens now? etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have added the output and expected output, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a regular expression to replace all text.

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\s]*/', '', $needle);
```

That should work for you.

Comment: No worries. Regular expressions are quite powerful if you understand how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to just perform a json_decode rather than exploding the data, especially when you have whitespaces, which doesnt work in all cases. Use json_decode in place of the exploding.

Comment: the result is not a valid json string.

Comment: I hadn't known about that, I'm quite new to coding, but I was told that I couldn't use json with it.  I'll try though.  Thanks.

Comment: You can read here more about json and how to use it. Also it contains some examples. Check it out.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

This is an issues with google currency converter. Try with this code for replacing the white-space between currencies:

```
$currency = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9.]/', '', $currency);
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried al replaces that I found via google itself and only yours worked!